# Forestplot R - expanding plot, edit a variable name

Tags: r, data-visualization, r-forestplot

I prepared a code to visualize my data:

```
    library(forestplot)
test_data <- data.frame(coef=c(1.14, 0.31, 10.70),
                        low=c(1.01, 0.12, 1.14),
                        high=c(1.30, 0.83, 100.16),
                        boxsize=c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
row_names <- cbind(c("Variable", "Variable 1", "Variable 2", "So looooooong and nasty name of the variable"),
                   c("OR", test_data$coef), c("CI -95%",  test_data$low), c("CI +95%", test_data$high) )
test_data <- rbind(rep(NA, 4), test_data)
forestplot(labeltext = row_names,
           mean = test_data$coef, upper = test_data$high,
           lower = test_data$low,
           is.summary=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
           boxsize = test_data$boxsize,
           zero = 1,
           xlog = TRUE,
           xlab = "OR (95% CI)",
           col = fpColors(lines="black", box="black"),
           title="My Happy Happy Title \n o happy happy title...\n",
           ci.vertices = TRUE,
           xticks = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100))
```

It gives a following forestplot:

[image: forestplot]

I would like to:

1) expand the plot and diminish font of the plot details on the left for better visualization

2) edit "So looooooong and nasty name of the variable" to move part "name..." below the row like:
"
So looooooong and nasty
name of the variable
"
However, when I write as "/nSo.../n" it gives another row of number from columns "OR" and "CIs".

How correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possibilities (one more than you asked for):

1) change text of row labels with `txt_gp`.

2) cut column spacing from 6 mm default to half that value by passing `colgap` a grid call to unit. Fully understanding the options for `forestplot` requires understanding the `grid` system of plotting.

3) add a `"\n"` to the loooong label. (I'm puzzled you didn't see that possibility, since you already had a "\n" in the title.)

```
row_names <- cbind(c("Variable", "Variable 1", "Variable 2", "So looooooong and \nnasty name of the variable"),
               c("OR", test_data$coef), c("CI -95%",  test_data$low), c("CI +95%", test_data$high) )

forestplot(labeltext = row_names,
           mean = test_data$coef, upper = test_data$high,
           lower = test_data$low,
           is.summary=c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
           boxsize = test_data$boxsize,
           zero = 1, colgap = unit(3, "mm"), txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label= gpar(cex = 0.7),
                                                             title = gpar(cex = 1) ),
           xlog = TRUE,
           xlab = "OR (95% CI)",
           col = fpColors(lines="black", box="black"),
           title="My Happy Happy Title \n o happy happy title...\n",
           ci.vertices = TRUE,
           xticks = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100))
```

[image]

If I only used a cex of 0.7 in the call to `gpar` passed to 'label', it also affected the size of the title, so I needed to "reset" the 'cex' of the 'title' back to 1.

Comment: Nice, thanks for help. Do you know how decrease interval between plot and title?

Comment: Well the first thing to do would be to remove the trailing "\n" from the title text. I had noticed the large gap but figured that's what you wnated.

Comment: @IRTFM Your answer is really helpful for many new bees in R. Can you please tell how can we make text BOLD for the variables who have significant HAZARD rATIOS?

Comment: Quick answer: I don't know off the top of my head. Warrants a new question. It should be easy to compose, since this one already has a ready made minimal reproducible example. My reasoning goes like this ... any question about a complex plot requires knowledge of the plotting paradigm and a thorough review of the function parameters. Since  the forestplot-package loads both `grid` and `maggritr` it seems likely that some extra research in the documentation and perhaps looking at the code will be required for those of us whose greatest experience is with `base` and `lattice` graphics.